# A Route 53 alias record points to a wrong CloudFront distribution but works. Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I manage 3 AWS accounts (for Route 53, production, and staging).

I created a Route 53 alias record for a subdomain that points to a CloudFront distribution of the STG environment.  It worked fine.

Then I decided to change it so that the subdomain would be resolved to the PROD and did the following.

1. I changed the alternate domain name of the STG distribution to empty.
2. I changed the alternate domain name of the PROD distribution to the subdomain.
3. But I forgot to update the Route 53 alias record.  So it still pointed to the STG, which had no alternate domain name.

However, it worked as intended.  The subdomain resolved to the PROD distribution without problems, and I didn't notice the wrong alias record configuration for a long time. Now I want to know how such a thing could happen. Is there any AWS document that explains how it handle an alias and route it to a possible CloudFront distribution somehow nicely?

Answer (score 0):

I see at [alternate-domain-names-restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions) that you can associate overlapping alternate domain names to 2 distributions using wildcards.

In this case CloudFront sends the request to the distribution with the more specific name match, regardless of the distribution that the DNS record points to.

So the capability to ignore your DNS record is baked in.